# Getting error in initialising the vector in C++

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int>v{2,3,4};
    cout<<v[0]; // output should be 2
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the ans to be 2 but it is giving error:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/harshtayal/Desktop/C++ Learn/" && g++ file.cpp -o file && "/Users/harshtayal/Desktop/C++ Learn/"file
file.cpp:5:17: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    vector<int>v{2,3,4};
                ^
                ;
1 error generated.
```

It is working when using push_back, but what's the problem in above??

Comment: Your c++ standard version is too old. Should be c++11 at least.

Comment: Make sure you have C++11 support enabled (`-std=c++11` or higher). See [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) on cppference.